# Usage of "transfer/transport oxygen"

Tags: word-usage

Is the usage of transfer/transport oxygen in the following sentence correct?

> Exercise is good for your mind as well, since it allows your body to **transfer** oxygen to you brain more efficiently.
>
> Exercise is good for your mind as well, since it allows your body to **transport** oxygen to you brain more efficiently.

Comment: Transfer:
To move or carry (goods, for example) from one place to another


VS


Transport:
To convey or cause to pass from one place, person, or thing to another.


The difference is "move" and "carry (goods)" in comparison with "cause to pass", but I'll wait for answers this question is a good one from my point of view because I wanna know the difference.

Comment: Like this question, used it regularly for Science but stupidly don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get more specific. What of your body does this job?

> Exercise may help the blood stream, or the blood, **to deliver** oxygen to the brain more efficiently.

*Transfer* is not appropriate here. *Transport* is okay. *Deliver* is most often used.

Comment: _Transfer_ could be appropriate – if the author is trying to say that exercise helps improve how oxygen is absorbed from the bloodstream by from brain. (That may not be likely, but I'm no neuroscientist. Exercise has a lot of counterintuitive benefits, including [affecting brain structure](https://blog.bufferapp.com/inactivity-and-the-brain-why-exercise-is-more-important-than-ever)).

Comment: Can you elaborate why *transfer* is unappropriated grammatically/technically/specifically here? It'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second example, though it is hard to say technically without more medical details (possibly either could be OK).

As a language matter, I think you need to think of this in two parts.

First, *transfer* implies a short term/distance movement from A to B. *transport* indicates more time or distance is involved.

> Oxygen from the lungs **transfers** to the red blood cells.

Then,

> The flow of blood **transports** oxygen from the lungs to the brain.

For another example, let's say you sending freight from Seattle to San Francisco, and it changes trucks in Portland. Then you could say:

> The shipment will **transfer** between trucks A and B in Portland.

and:

> The company C will **transport** the shipment from Seattle to San Francisco.

You could use this example with people, though you would probably use *travel* instead of *transport*.

> We will **travel** from Seattle to San Francisco. We will **transfer** between train A and train B in Portland.